# Error: Index out of bounds - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, indexing

I am still fairly new to Python and I am attempting to run a for loop. However, I receive an error indicating that my index is out of bounds. I'm not sure what exactly the problem is, any help is appreciated!

My code and error are both below:

```
croot = 1
ctip = 1
span = 1
thetaroot = 0
thetatip = 0
a0root = 0.11
a0tip = 0.11
alpha = 0
alpha0root = -2.5
alpha0tip = -2.5
thetaroot = thetaroot * atan(1.) / 45.
thetatip = thetatip * atan(1.) / 45.
alpha = alpha * atan(1.) / 45.
alpha0root = alpha0root * atan(1.) / 45.
alpha0tip = alpha0tip * atan(1.) / 45.
n = 10
theta = zeros((1,n))
y = zeros((1,n))
c = zeros((1,n))
cl = zeros((1,n))
alp = zeros((1,n))
a = zeros((1,n))
rhs = zeros((n,1))
b = zeros((n,1))
a = zeros((n,1))
#
# Define properties at n span stations
#
pi = 4. * atan(1.)
for i in range(1,n):
    theta[i] = i * pi / (2. * n)
    y[i] = span * 0.5 * cos(theta[i])
    c[i] = croot + (ctip - croot) * y[i] * 2. / span
    alp[i] = alpha + thetaroot - (alpha0root + (alpha0tip - alpha0root + thetaroot - thetatip) * y[i] * 2. / span)
    a[i] = a0root + (a0tip - a0root) * y[i] * 2. / span

pi = 4. * atan(1)
```

I then receive the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-8710173d8f43> in <module>()
     29 pi = 4. * atan(1.)
     30 for i in range(1,n):
---> 31     theta[i] = i * pi / (2. * n)
     32     y[i] = span * 0.5 * cos(theta[i])
     33     c[i] = croot + (ctip - croot) * y[i] * 2. / span

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Comment: I assume that you're using numpy?

Comment: Yes, numpy was imported.

Comment: As pointed out below - you should use range(0, n) (or just range(n), it's the same thing) because python is 0-indexed, not 1-indexed (like, say Octave). Looking at what you're doing though, it looks as though you could do this in a 'vectorized' way without using the loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in the comments that you are using numpy.zeros here, the value of theta in your code will be

```
theta = array([0,0,0]) # If size of n is 3
```

If you wish to add elements to theta like
theta = array([0, 1, 2]), you have to do it like this:

theta[0][i] = i * pi / (2. * n)

And this goes with your variables y, c, alp, a as well. This will be the code:

```
croot = 1
ctip = 1
span = 1
thetaroot = 0
thetatip = 0
a0root = 0.11
a0tip = 0.11
alpha = 0
alpha0root = -2.5
alpha0tip = -2.5
thetaroot = thetaroot * atan(1.) / 45.
thetatip = thetatip * atan(1.) / 45.
alpha = alpha * atan(1.) / 45.
alpha0root = alpha0root * atan(1.) / 45.
alpha0tip = alpha0tip * atan(1.) / 45.
n = 10
theta = zeros((1,n))
y = zeros((1,n))
c = zeros((1,n))
cl = zeros((1,n))
alp = zeros((1,n))
a = zeros((1,n))
rhs = zeros((n,1))
b = zeros((n,1))
a = zeros((n,1)) # There are 2 definitions of a here which is not good
#
# Define properties at n span stations
#
pi = 4. * atan(1.)
for i in range(1,n):
    theta[0][i] = i * pi / (2. * n)
    y[0][i] = span * 0.5 * cos(theta[0][i])
    c[0][i] = croot + (ctip - croot) * y[i] * 2. / span
    alp[0][i] = alpha + thetaroot - (alpha0root + (alpha0tip - alpha0root + thetaroot - thetatip) * y[0][i] * 2. / span)
    a[i][0] = a0root + (a0tip - a0root) * y[0][i] * 2. / span
    #Or use a[0][i] if a is defined as a = zeros((1, n)), the first definition

pi = 4. * atan(1)
```

In case you wish to add elements like

```
theta = array([0,0,0], [1,1,1], [2,2,2])
```

Then modify the for loop as follows:

```
for i in range(1,n):
    theta += i * pi / (2. * n)
    y += span * 0.5 * cos(theta[i])
    c += croot + (ctip - croot) * y[i] * 2. / span
    alp += alpha + thetaroot - (alpha0root + (alpha0tip - alpha0root + thetaroot - thetatip) * y[i] * 2. / span)
    a += a0root + (a0tip - a0root) * y[i] * 2. / span
```

Comment: Your code fixes most of the lines, but I still get an error for line 35 where a[0][i] is called. Same error as before.

Comment: That's because I missed the later a which makes a to build zeros((n,1)). I will fix my answer. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `zeros` function of numpy generate a structure like `[[0. 0. 0. 0. ...]]`
So to access the first element you need to do `theta[0][0]`.

Your loop need to be like :

```
for i in range(n):
    theta[0][i] = #your code
```

same thing for all your array generate by `zeros()`.

`zeros` function return a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

When executing `theta = zeros((1,n))` with n = 10 will return

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Which is `one list contains one list inside`. The outter list contains only one element at index 0 and you cannot access it at index 1....n

To fix this, try this:

```
theta[0][i] = i * pi / (2. * n)
```